Cloudflare appears to be blocking request content in my python application
I am in a somewhat unusual situation. I am developing a reverse-proxy software that will hopefully act as a one-size-fits-all for the generation of 1-time links, for sites that I want to send to people but would rather not be webscraped or analyzed. I like to use cloudflare as a host because its very low effort and easy to set up on a new server or whatnot, and as a one man army time is often of the essence. My reverse-proxy software is working reasonably well, but when i host on cloudflare with the "Flexible" option I get a peculiar error. It looks like I am receiving all the headers from get requests just fine, buy none of the content. For reference, here is the relevant code snippet:
        def do_GET(self, body=True):
        if not self.validate_request():
            self.send_response(302)
            self.send_header("location", "https://innocuous.website")
            self.end_headers()
            return
        # Forward the request to another host and port
        target_host = hostname  # Change this to your target host
        
        # Construct the URL for the target host
        target_url = f"http://{target_host}{self.path}"
        
        # Extract headers from the original request
        headers = {header: value for header, value in self.headers.items()}

        print(headers)

        content_length = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        
        # Forward the GET request using requests library
        try:
            response = requests.get(target_url, headers=headers, data=body, allow_redirects=False)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            self.send_error(500, str(e))
            return
        
        # Send the response back to the client
        self.send_response(response.status_code)
        for header, value in response.headers.items():
            print(header, " : ", value)
            self.send_header(header, value)
        if (self.new_cookie != ''):
            self.send_header("Set-Cookie", "anticrawler_id=" + self.new_cookie)
            self.new_cookie = ''
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response.content)
        self.wfile.flush()

From debugging I know that all of the relevant information is successfully sent to the proxy application, to the site behind the proxy, and then the information is retrieved back to the proxy successfully, and I also know that the headers are successfully transmitted back to the site visitor. However, none of the response body makes it back to the visitor, and in console I get this message:
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('141.101.105.137', 14080)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socketserver.py", line 692, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socketserver.py", line 362, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socketserver.py", line 761, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\server.py", line 438, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\server.py", line 404, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 707, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------


Everything works fine without cloudflare, save for a weird loading bug which I might submit a separate issue about. I would like to get this to work with cloudflare because my opps might try to ddos me at a critical moment if I don't. Thanks!
I have tried adding the flush to the code which only made the error more frequent (before that it would never work but only occasionally display the error).

Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it.

we do not have the code for "handle_one_request" with the readline call. Note that you HTTP server seems to know only HTTP/1.0, for HTTP/1.1 support you would need to ensure Transfer-Encoding 'chunked' support for body transmission is supported. So be sure to enforce HTTP/1.0 in all your first lines protocol version. And... from experience, a simple reverse proxy does not exists, be sure to read all the RFC, especially on security problems. I would try to reuse existing HTTP libraries and extend it, and never try to redo the low level protocol stuff.
